# git svn clone for subset of svn repository shows error message

Tags: git, git-svn

The svn repository is

```
http://example.com/svn/a/b/c
http://example.com/svn/b/c
http://example.com/svn/c/d/e
http://example.com/svn/d/e/f
```

I want to clone the subset,

```
git svn clone -r HEAD -t http://example.com/svn --include-paths '(a/b/c|b/c|d/e/f)'
```

It shows the following error message:

```
SVN repository location required as a command-line argument
```

Comment: Just fell over your question. Couldn't fail to notice that the `-t` arguments reads as "`-t<tags_subdir>`". So, it's a parameter pointing to tags, not trunk.

Answer (score 1):

The `-t` switch needs an argument, with it you tell `git-svn` which path leads to the trunk. In your case you say your trunk is in the directory `http://example.com/svn` and so there is no URL specified which the error message tells you. In your case you probably don't want the `-t` switch.